# setTimeout in combination with onmouseout

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout, onmouseout

I'm trying to get the "onmouseout" function on a delay. So that when you move the mouse the video returns to the poster after a few seconds. The following code instantly returns you to the poster onmouseout.

```
<video class="content" 
    poster="/video/test.jpg"
    width="320" 
    height="240"  
    loop onmouseover="this.play()" 
    onmouseout="this.load();" >
        <source src="/video/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

The following code is a working example I can get something to work after a delay of onmouseout:

```
 <video class="content" 
        poster="/video/test.jpg"
        width="320" 
        height="240"  
        loop onmouseover="this.play()" 
        onmouseout="myFunction();" >


        <script>
            function myFunction() {
              setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
            }
            </script>

<source src="/video/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

How do i get "this.load" in setTimeout?

Comment: Welcome!  You need to bring whatever the context of `this` into the setTimeout.  Not `this` itself but what `this.load` is pointing to.  I'm guessing if you open the console you will see an error like `this.load` is not a function?

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks for your reply!. I'm making my first website using 99% html & css. This is the only "fancy" part as of now using minimal javascript code of which i know very little of. Thanks for the tip but I don't know exactly how to bring the context of this.load into the javascript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setTimeout accepts a function as its first parameter so you can pass `this.load` as the first parameter and use it in the onmouseout attribute as such:

```
<video  class="content" 
        poster="/video/test.jpg"
        width="320" 
        height="240"  
        loop 
        onmouseover="this.play()" 
        onmouseout="setTimeout(this.load.bind(this), 3000)" >
    <source src="/video/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

edit: I had a bug (sorry) I'm now using bind function to bind the video element to the `load` function.
However it's not the best way to do it because if you use the `onmouseout` property or any other HTML property that attach events, you can only attach one `onmouseout` event. In most cases you would want to attach more than one. So a better solution would be using the `addEventListener` method:

HTML:

```
<video  id="content-video"
        class="content" 
        poster="/video/test.jpg"
        width="320" 
        height="240" >
    <source src="/video/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

JS:

```
const video = document.getElementById("content-video");
video.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    video.play();
}, false);
video.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    setTimeout(video.load.bind(video), 3000);
}, false);
```

edit: I'm really sorry about the bugs. I fixed them and it's working now.

Comment: Hi Saar! Thank you very much for your reply. I'm not getting any results with it though :(.

Your first expample plays the video on mouseover but doesn't do anything on onmouseout..


<video  class="content" 
        poster="/video/test.jpg"
        width="320" 
        height="240"  
        loop 
        onmouseover="this.play()" 
        onmouseout="setTimeout(this.load, 3000);" >
    <source src="/video/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

Your second option I can't get working. Neither the onmouseover or the onmouseout. I will post the whole code later today.

Comment: You're right! I had to bind the load function to the video element. sorry for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Saar, this is working perfectly!! I upvoted your awnser but due to my low reputation nothing happened.
Very much appreciated!!!